# How to create a variable that can take strings and functions in Kotlin?

Tags: dynamic, types, kotlin

Is there a way to create a variable to store strings and functions? Like `var x:dynamic` where x can be any type or a function: `x="foo"; x= {print (...)}`

`dynamic` isn't a type (it just turns off type checking) and works only in kotlin.js (JavaScript). Is there a type that includes function types and Any?

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have union types, so the best you've got is `Any`. But why do you really have to store strings and functions in the same variable?

Comment: I want to know the relationship between Any and function types.

Comment: `Any` is just `Object`. Functional objects are objects. That's the only common thing you'll find. There can't _be_ a type including `Any` because `Any` _is_ a superclass of everything.

Comment: I'd recommend a sealed class because you have a closed set of possible types. `Any` is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this code and works fine.
The var x is Any so it can hold any kind of data (not nullable ) in it. To hold nullable data use Any?

```
        var x: Any = "foo"
        println( x )

        x = { println("") }
        x.invoke()
```

The IDE smart cast the variable but you can help the cast using this

```
       (x as ()->Unit).invoke()
```